# How to parse body parts of a MIME message by using mimetic library?

Tags: c++, pop3

I'm fighting with a problem here, and maybe you can give me a hand. I'm processing a POP3 Email account which i need for parsing the emails and getting into its information. I was using **libCurl** for read the mails, and i'm currently using **mimetic** library for dismember each part of the email inside. 
The fact is that i could do this easily for the "header" of the email, but i don't know how to do this for the body. This is my code right now:

```
void MailServer::PrintMimeStructure(MimeEntity* pMe)
{
    Header& h = pMe->header();  

    Body& b = pMe->body(); //i don't know how to access here!   
    ContentType ct = h.contentType();
    ContentId ci = h.contentId();
    ContentDisposition cd = h.contentDisposition(); 
    if(h.hasField("subject"))
        cout << "<subject>" << h.field("subject").value() << "</subject>" << 
        endl;

    if(h.hasField("from"))
        cout << "<from>" << h.field("from").value() << "</from>" << 
        endl;
    if(h.hasField("to"))
        cout << "<to>" << h.field("to").value() << "</to>" << 
        endl;
    if(h.hasField("message-id"))
        cout << "<message-id>" << h.field("message-id").value() << "</message-id>" << 
        endl;

    if(h.hasField("date"))
        cout << "<date>" << h.field("date").value() << "</date>" << 
        endl;

    //WHAT ABOUT THE BODY??
}
```

and this is what it prints: 
[image]
-- as you can see, is very easy to getting into the heading by using this tool, but digging into the body object properties, i don't have any **"field"** method useful to get the attachments for example, which is what i need.

Anyway, i'll appreciate any help from you guys! i'm stucked here!

Comment: What you need is to learn how to use Mimetic to decode multi-part MIME messages. Does it have any documentation?

Comment: yes, i saw it, but only shows an example to do this task for the header as i did here, but is kind of poor for the body. Believe me, i really tried to find something but there's nothing out there.

Comment: I accept any suggestion for other useful library for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Body class has overloaded operator <<.
You can get string representation of body with the following method:

```
 std::stringstream s;
 s << pMe->body();
 std::string bodyStr = s.str();
```